# Number of subgroups of $G$ conjugate to $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I need help in understanding following problem.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\leq G$. Prove that the number of subgroups of $G$
conjugate to $H$ is a divisor of $|G|$.

I want to understand what does a subgroup conjugate to $H$  mean.

Does it mean that every element of that subgroup is conjugate to every element in $H$.

That is for $K\leq G$ to be conjugate to $H$.

For every $k\in K$ $ \exists x_{i} \in G $ such that $k= x_{i}^{-1}H x_{i}$ where $ i = {1,....,|H|}$

I have been thinking about this for a while. I just want to make sure I am on the right track. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of conjugates of $H$ is equal to the index of the normaliser of $H$ in $G$, i.e. $\,\dfrac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert N_G(H)\rvert}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. It's getting late here….

Comment: is that something that needs to be proven or does it follow immediately from the definitions?

Comment: In my opinion, it follows from the definitions; $G$ acts by conjugation on the set of its subgroups and the normaliser is the subgroup  of elements which fix $H$. It's just the transcription of the class formula for this specific case.

Comment: one more thing. If, say $|G:H|=n$, then is the number of subgroups of $G$ conjugate to $H$ a divisor of $|G|$ or is it a divisor of $n$?

Comment: It's a divisor of $n$, hence a divisor of $\lvert G\rvert$ since $\;[G\colon H]=[G\colon N_G(H)]\cdot[ N_G(H)\colon H]$.

Comment: I've never seen that equality before. Do you know where I could find a proof of it?

Comment: erp. Nevermind. It's a pretty standard thing.

Comment: The equality is valid for any tower of subgroups: $H\subset K\subset G$, not only with the normaliser.

Comment: yeah, I realized that when I found it in my notes as a stronger form of Lagrange's Theorem. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ are conjugate if there exists a $g\in G$ such that $g^{-1}Hg=K$.

Comment: In particular, this is different to what you wrote.